# Using Type T in swift Playground

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I am trying to follow along with the playground video on the WWDC page, but for some reason I am getting this error now. I switch to beta 3 of Xcode 6 and I noticed they changed some stuff, such as array syntax but why can't by Type T work? [image]

I'm assuming something changed from the first beta to the third with this that I am not aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is rather cryptic and doesn't really tell you what the problem is.

In this case, the `data` argument needs to be an `inout` parameter, since you are modifying it and expect the changes to be available outside the function.

You should change your function to:

```
func exchange<T>(inout data: [T], i: Int, j: Int) {
    let temp = data[i]
    data[i] = data[j]
    data[j] = temp
}
```

And when calling it, prepend the data argument with `&`.

```
exchange(&someData, someInt, anotherInt)
```

Comment: Ah perfect! Thank you. Lucky enough the complier prepended it for me :)